# HTML5 Scrolling background

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, requestanimationframe

I'm making an html5 "web-game-style" and I got a large width background around 7600px. The background is set using the css background-size: 100% 100% in a div who have the 400vw width. Im trying to scroll over that background using the window.scrollBy function inside requestAnimationFrame loop. Ramdomly while the page is autoscrolling the background gets graphical gliches but the rendreing timeline(Chrome) show me times less than 2ms in paintings.

```
dpl = -window.innerWidth*duration;
    if(next != null){
        function move(){
            if(window.pageXOffset > next.x){
                window.scrollBy(dpl,0);
                window.requestAnimationFrame(move);
            }else{
                window.scrollTo(next.x,next.y);
                actual = next;
                next = null;
            }
        };
        move();
            //Interval callback
            /*interval = setInterval(function(){
            if(window.pageXOffset > next.x){
                window.scrollBy(dpl,0);
            }else{
                window.scrollTo(next.x,next.y);
                actual = next;
                next = null;
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        },scrollInterval);*/
    }
```

I also tried changing the scrollBy function and using a css tranformation and transition fired changing the class of the element who changes the translate3d property to try to force the gpu..Again the same result...

```
.camLeft{
-ms-transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0) !important; 
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0) !important;
transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0) !important;
}
```

and using:

```
$(".btnLeft").click(function(){
   $("#background").toggleClass("camLeft");
});
```

Another try was using a canvas.. Again with the requestAnimationFrame loop and scrolling the background clearing the canvas every frame and repainting the background..(canvas here got 100%/100% and image 400%/100% setted up on window load)...Again the same result. Painting times less than 2ms sometimes 4-5 ms but randomly graphical gliches.

I dunno what else to do except try to make the background by tiles or pices what will be alot of work. When the background moves alot of area of the screen got "damanged" so make it by tiles dunno if it will be the solution cuz while scrolling alot of tiles will need to be moved.

Note: the background is made in svg also  tried png and it makes more gliches.Its a basic floor background unicolor with alot of curves like 2D platform game

Thanks alot for the help.